Map Array of Bigints to String / Bigint
I have an array of ids that I want to map to to a unique string + bigint key (e.g. ARRAY[1, 2, 3] -> 'ABC' / 1, ARRAY[1, 4] -> 'DEF' / 2, ARRAY[5, 6, 9] -> 'GHI' / 3). What's the simplest way to accomplish this? The array sizes are variable and have some member overlap (i.e. want to distinguish between ARRAY[1, 2, 3] vs ARRAY[2, 3] vs ARRAY[1, 2, 4]). This is part of a pipeline that will run on a regular basis with new ids being introduced, so each array mapping has to stay consistent and I also have to be able to add new keys.
My original thought was to use a Set Digest object, but I don't see a quick way to cast it into a string representation. Thanks in advance.

How long those arrays are? Maybe you just concatenate with some separator?
